# Codificação de texto (erro de acentuação)

Tags: php

O código php:

```
case 'countries':
            $array = array (
                        'city1        ' => __('Acrelândia - AC',"ultimatemember")
```

Dentro do plugin no wordpress para escolher a opção criada no php

[image: Escolhendo a cidade]
Visualizando a opção escolhida.

[image: Depois de escolhida]
Já tentei incluir  nas páginas, já tentei converter as arrays para UTF8 e nada.

Comment: Ola, O constrangimento está após o post para gravar. Já alterou na pagina de gravação o encode?

Comment: Presico procurar essa página, vou testar.

Comment: Será que adicionar: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); na página de gravação da certo?

Comment: É onde está o constragimento. Tentou?

Comment: Já tentei algumas páginas, acho que estou editando a página errada, mas será que só de adicionar o charset utf-8 no local correto dará certo? Eu verifiquei que o banco está gravando com acentuação errada.

Comment: Com os dados fornecidos não existe garantia. Pode ser charset da pagina como pode ser tambem o proprio ficheiro. Está editar as paginas com que editor? Em que charset está a gravar o ficheiro?

Comment: Não entendi @TiagoGomes

Comment: Os editores de texto por exemplo o notepad++ gravam o ficheiro em varios charset, que tambem podem causar alguns constrangimentos.